# How Google Sheet API Provides regional support?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am using google sheet apis in my project but I also need to provide support for EU region.I couldn't find google Sheet EU regional endpoint or something to Provide a support for EU region.If it provides support then how it can be done or how it does? Can someone help me to get this answer.These [APIs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) of google sheets, I am using in my project.

Comment: Why do you need a EU-specific endpoint?

Comment: @Quentin We are integrating google sheet in our project and we want to provide a support to end user to select the region .
for example :- we have also integrated the BlueShift in our project and [here](https://help.blueshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404624313235-Blueshift-global-regions) are the regional support it provides.

Comment: That sounds like circular logic. You want an EU-specific end point so your end users can pick an EU-specific end point? Why do you want to provide that feature? What benefit will it give to your end users?